# redis server does not create socket file

Tags: redis, gitlab

I'm trying to install gitlab on my apache2 server using this tutorial : http://blog.florentlim.com/how-to-install-gitlab-on-debian-7-wheezy-on-apache2-http-server/
Everything seemed to go correctly, I've done every step, without any major problems.

But now when I try to connect on my gitlab page, it shows up a "error 500 page". Looking at my gilab production.log , it looks like gilab can't connect on the /var/run/redis/redis.socket file, and sure enough, there is no such file. And I don't know why...
I verified my /etc/redis/redis.conf file, the TCP port is set to 0, and I've got the lines

```
unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock
unixsocketperm 770
```

So why does redis refuses to create my socket?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does /var/run/redis/ exist?
Does whatever user is redis running have permission to write in the directory?

Comment: ok, I'm feeling really dumb on this one. It was a permission issue indeed. Thanks

Comment: Also, I found that I needed to run the redis-server using sudo in order for the socket file to be created.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but on a derivative of Arch Linux.

Redis had to be installed for OpenVAS and I was getting a permission error after attempting to start the service like this:

```
systemctl start redis.service
```

The error was visible using:

```
journalctl -xeu redis.service
```

as recommended by the `systemctl` command output.

When it attempted to create the Unix socket in `/run` (also linked from `/var/run`) it would fail because it could not create the file. I could manually created a `redis` subdirectory under `/run` using `sudo` and change the owner to the `redis` user then started `redis` but the directory kept disappearing later.

I tried re-installing with pacman because I was a bit lost but that didn't seem to help.

---

**Solution in my case**

After running

```sh
sudo systemctl enable redis.service
```

I can start the service and `/run/redis` (also linked as `/var/run/redis`) is present with a PID and Unix socket file as configured with the `unixsocket` entry in my config file.

I can confirm it's accessible with:

```
redis-cli -s /run/redis/redis.sock
```

After a reboot it's still good.